# When should the ERC-1155 Metadata URI need to be zero-padded to 64 hex characters?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

EIP-155 states that the "The string format of the substituted hexadecimal ID ***MUST*** be leading zero padded to 64 hex characters length ***if necessary***."

In what situation is a 0-padded hex ID necessary? It is odd they chose to use the keyword ****MUST**** here as it seems like the choice of whether to use 64 hex character padding is completely arbitrary.

I understand that there cannot exist more than 2^256 ids (64 hex digits), but wouldn't the choice of metadata URI for an ERC-1155 token be implementation-dependent?

For example, if I wanted to create an ERC-1155 token composed only of 64 NFTs, I'd much prefer defining metadata URLs as follows:

```
https://{DOMAIN}/1.json
https://{DOMAIN}/2.json
...
https://{DOMAIN}/40.json (64 in hex)
```

Comment: "In what situation is a 0-padded hex ID necessary?" If the string format of the substituted hexadecimal ID is less than 64 hex characters?

Answer (score 1):

*I suspect* that ERC-1155 was built with uint256 in mind as the standard for numeric types and that requiring ID to be padded to 64 hex characters means that all 256 bits of information are specified explicitly. Maybe this alleviates potential issues with dirty leading bits?

Padding doesn't appear to be strictly necessary to function - I have seen smart contracts which use unpadded metadata URLs, such as Mining.game
(https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x1a3d0451f48ebef398dd4c134ae60846274b7ce0#code),
(https://api.mining.game/1.json).

This is on the Polygon testnet, not a mainnet, so keep in mind that code quality may not be stellar. But regardless, it appears to work.